# latitude, longitude to grid reference in php

Tags: php, gps

Can anyone point at a tutorial for calculating the grid reference from lat long.

I have lat and long coordinates from a gps tracker but I need a way to convert them to grid reference norths and eastings.

Comment: Do you mean UTM Grid? There are many differnet grid coordinate reference systems

Comment: Yes Sorry I did mean UTM, thanks I missed that off

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert from latitude, longitude based on WGS84, which is the default for GPS chips, to UTM WGS84 the you can find opens source software for that task.:
search for WGS84 to UTM conversion) or use this: [Open source PHP function for converting UTM coordinates to latitude and longtitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203295/open-source-php-function-for-converting-utm-coordinates-to-latitude-and-longtitu)

If you need advanced conversions like, convert to UTM which is not based on WGS84 like UTM ED50 (Italy) or UTM NAD27 (USA),
then you need a professional coordinate transformation library.